# Panel Containing PictureBox Not Scrolling

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a Windows Forms application that contains a TabControl that I am using to display an image for each TabPage.

Inside the TabPage I place a CustomControl for displaying the image. The CustomControl has some checkboxes for setting the image layout, PictureBox, and a Button to remove the image. This is what my Custom Control looks like:

[image: Image Preview Custom Control]

I want the PictureBox to be scrollable so in order to do so I add a Panel to the CustomControl:

[image: Image Preview Custom Control - Panel]

I set the Anchor property of this Panel to *Left|Right|Top|Bottom* and the AutoScroll property to *True*.

Next, I place the PictureBox inside the Panel I set its Anchor property to *Left|Right|Top|Bottom* and SizeMode to *AutoSize*:

[image: Image Preview Custom Control - PictureBox]

When I start my application and I click an "Add Image" button I programatically add a new TabPage containing my CustomControl then add the image to the CustomControl:

```
// inside my main forms callback
ImagePreviewCustomControl previewControl = new ImagePreviewCustomControl(bitMap);
previewControl.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
TabPage tabPage = new TabPage(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(imageFileName));                
tabPage.Controls.Add(previewControl);
imagesTabControl.TabPages.Add(tabPage);

// inside the custom control after the constructor
imagePreviewPictureBox.BackgroundImage = bitMap;
imagePreviewPictureBox.BackgroundImageLayout = imageLayout;
```

I don't see any scrollbars, however, if the image added is bigger than the PictureBox. (The image dimensions are 1035 x 1024 so it's much bigger than the PictureBox.)

Here is a screenshot:

[image: Tab Control With TabPage Containing Picture]

Am I setting the properties of either the Panel or PictureBox incorrectly? If so, what do I need to do?

Thank you.

*==UPDATE==================================*

I changed the Anchor property of the PictureBox to none as suggested. Here is my updated layout:

[image: Image Preview Custom Control - PictureBox]

However this still doesn't work. I am seeing the same issue. No scrollbars

Could this have something to do with the fact that when I add the CustomControl to the TabPage I set it's Dock to *Fill*?

```
ImagePreviewCustomControl previewControl = new ImagePreviewCustomControl(bitMap);
previewControl.Dock = DockStyle.Fill; // << << <<
TabPage tabPage = new TabPage(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(imageFileName));                
tabPage.Controls.Add(previewControl);
imagesTabControl.TabPages.Add(tabPage);
```

*==========================================*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Next, I place the PictureBox inside the Panel I set its Anchor property to Left|Right|Top|Bottom ...

And thus the `Panel` doesn't need to scroll because the picture box never goes outside the view port. Don't `Anchor` the picture box.

Comment: Should I set the Dock to anything?

Comment: @JanTacci, nope. Setting the `Dock` will basically do the same thing. Just let the picture box grow and shrink with its content. You could *technically* set the `Anchor` to `Top|Left` I guess, but I think you can leave that alone because that should be the **default.**

Comment: What about the underlying panel? What should it's Dock/Anchor properties be?

Comment: @JanTacci, the `Panel` is fine. You've got it set to grow with its parent because it's anchored to all sides.

Comment: You said: *"You've got it set to grow with its parent because it's anchored to all sides"* Is that correct for the Panel?

Comment: Please look at my updated question under *UPDATE*. This shows my new settings, however, it still doesn't work. Could this have something to do with the fact that when I add the CustomControl to the TabPage I set it's Dock to *Fill*?

Comment: I am accepting your answer. However, I found out what I need to do in addition to your suggestion. I needed to dynamically set the picture box size when the image is added.

Comment: There is some kind of bug when I stretch the picture. First, i scroll down a big picture, then I stretch and unstretch, there is a big empty space on the top of the picture.